MySQL: How to make a trigger that updates a table after a deletion in a related table?
I have a database with 2 relevant tables: animals and movement. The movement table tracks animal movements. The animals table has animal_id as the primary key, and which is a foreign key in the movement table. I want to make a trigger that deletes any relevant rows in the movement table when an animal is deleted from the animals table.
The code for what I've tried:
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER before_animal_delete 
BEFORE DELETE 
ON animals 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO movement(animal_id, movement_type, reason, date)    
    VALUES (OLD.animal_id, 'emigrate', 'migration', NOW());

END; //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_animal_delete 
AFTER DELETE 
ON animals 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO movement(animal_id, movement_type, reason, date) 
    VALUES (OLD.animal_id, 'emigrate', 'migration', NOW()); 
    
END; //
DELIMITER ; 

I expected the movement table to delete any records (rows) of the animal deleted after deleting an animal from the animals table, but what happened was that the records in the movement table stayed, even after deleting the animal in question. What did I do wrong?

Your triggers are inserting into the movement table, not deleting. Why would you expect an INSERT statement to DELETE anything? Maybe you should have a read about foreign keys and cascading deletes - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
